# Calculating number of substring occurrences and returning score

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on this project where I have this MySQL database with a table named "speechesLCMcoded" with thousands of lines of parsed text. I have four columns that are "key", "parsed", "weight" and "count".

The text in the column "parsed" looks like this:

```
{N}table{/N}{V}play{/V}{A}big{/A}
```

I have another table that is named "concreteness" that has two columns, In the column "word" I have a list of words and in the column "score" I have each word's concreteness score. For example it would look like this

```
Word    Score 
table   5 
play    3 
big     2
```

I am working on a php script that will calculate for each line of my table "speechesLCMcoded" the total cumulated score of each word and the total number of scored words.

In my example, the result would look like this:

```
Key    parsed                            weight    count
1     {N}table{/N}{V}play{/V}{A}big{/A}  10        3
```

I have written a part of the script but I am stuck because of my limited experience with php. I am confused by the fact that there are two "while" loops in my script

How would you advise me to do?

```
<?php
//Include functions
        include "functions.php";
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 90000);
        echo 'Time Limit = ' . ini_get('max_execution_time');

//Conecting the database
        if (!$conn) {
         die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());}

// make LCM the current db
        mysql_select_db('senate');
        $data = mysql_query("SELECT `key`, `tagged` FROM speecheLCMcoded") 
        or die(mysql_error()); 

// puts the "data" info into the $info array 
        while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data) ){
        $key=$info['key'];
        $tagged=$info['tagged'];

// Print out the contents of the entry 
        Print "<b>Key:</b> ".$info['key'] .  " <br>";  

// Select Word List and their weights
        $dataweights = mysql_query("SELECT `word`, `weight` FROM concreteness") 
        or die(mysql_error()); 

// puts the "data" info into the $infoweights array 
        while($infoweights = mysql_fetch_array( $infoweights) ){
        $word=$info['word'];
        $score=$info['score'];      

// Calulate number of adjectives
        ob_start(); //Start output buffer
        print substr_count($tagged,"{"); 
        $adjectives = ob_get_contents(); //Grab output
        ob_end_clean(); //Discard output buffer

// Calulate number of coded items


//Saving number of coded words
        $sql = "UPDATE speechestest SET adjectives='$adjectives', verbs='$verbs', nouns='$nouns' WHERE `key`='$key';" ;
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
        if(! $retval )
        {die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());}
        echo "Updated data successfully\n";
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is the following:

```
o  Query the database to get your sentences

o  For each sentence (while loop) {

  o  Get a list of all the words in your sentence (by breaking up the sentence into words--c.f. explode and preg_match_all)

  o  For each word you found (while loop) {

    o  Query the database to get information about the word.

    o  Do whatever you need to do with the word data.
  }

}
```

I'm not providing code because that's your job  :)  Also, try writing out what you want to do in human-readable sentences, and then just replace those sentences with code.  It should make it more clear what you're doing and why you're doing it.

Comment: Hi, I did what you said and it works. The main problem now is that the script will most likely take weeks before it is done calculating all of the scores. I have 400K rows in my database and 80K in my lexicon. Would you have an idea on how to speed up the process?

Comment: Do you mean you have 400K sentences?  Well, if you have x words per sentence, then that's only 400,000(x+1) database calls.  Even if all of your sentences have 100 words, that's only 40,400,000 database calls.  I doubt that would take weeks.  If the database calls are what's slowing you down, you could load your lexicon into an associative array and just get info from that array instead of querying the database every time you want a word.  That would reduce it to 480,000 database calls.

Comment: Trying running the program on like 1,000 sentences and time it (call mktime before running, and mktime after, and subtract the end time from start time).  It would give you a fairly accurate estimate of how long the entire run will take.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually have way more data than one sentence per row. It can be up to 2 or 3 pages of a word document per row. I think I will let my computer run tonight with the script on and I will see tomorrow morning what happens.